# CLARION Date Conversion C# + DATE ADD/SUBTRACT

Tags: c#, t-sql, clarion

*(This is for ISV database so I am kind of reverse engineering this and cannot change) ...

How can I do the following date to int (visa/versa) conversion in C# ...

So Say the Date is:

```
5/17/2012
```

it gets converted to int

```
77207
```

in the database.

At first I thought this was a Julian date however it does not appear to be the case.  I was fooling around with the method from [Julian Date Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248827/convert-datetime-to-julian-date-in-c-sharp-tooadate-safe) however this does not match up.

```
   var date = ConvertToJulian(Convert.ToDateTime("5/17/2012"));
   Console.WriteLine(date);

    public static long ConvertToJulian(DateTime Date)
    {
        int Month = Date.Month;
        int Day = Date.Day;
        int Year = Date.Year;

        if (Month < 3)
        {
            Month = Month + 12;
            Year = Year - 1;
        }
        long JulianDay = Day + (153 * Month - 457) 
        / 5 + 365 * Year + (Year / 4) - 
        (Year / 100) + (Year / 400) + 1721119;
        return JulianDay;
    }

Outputs 2456055 //Should be 77207
```

I've been using this SQL to do the conversion:

```
SELECT Convert(date, CONVERT(CHAR,DATEADD(D, 77207, '1800-12-28'),101))
```

and it appears to be accurate.  How could I do this conversion in C# ?  And can someone edify me as to what standard this is based on or is it simply a random conversion.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to see if 5/18/2012 generates 77208 or if 5/16/2012 generates 77206?

Comment: @Josh Yes that is how I figured out that bit of sql ...5/18 = 77208 etc ...

Comment: Renaming For Future People running into this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a [Clarion Date](http://www.iprogrammable.com/2007/07/31/clarion-date-and-time-in-net/):

> the number of days that have elapsed since December 28, 1800

Allegedly to, [Display Clarion Dates In Excel](http://www.clarionmag.com/cmag/v4/v4n12exceldates.html) it only takes

> subtracting 36161 from the value and formatting it as a date

Comment: Good Call Josh, Great Links also

Answer (score 8):

```
//TO int
var date = new DateTime(1800,12,28,0,0,0);            
var daysSince = (DateTime.Now-date).Days;

//FROM int
var date = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28, 0, 0, 0);
var theDate = date.AddDays(77207);
```

Comment: I liked yours better - deleted mine

Answer (score 0):

If it is a linear formula, you should be able to calculate formula in the form of y=mx+b. You would need a minimum of two data points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vb.net Code I use to convert Clarion Date to Julian Date:

```
 Dim ldblDaysToSubtract As Double = 36161.0

 mclsRevEmployeeRecd.BirthDate(istrBirthDate:=(CDbl(E1Row.Item("BIRTH_DT")) - ldblDaysToSubtract).ToString)

 mstrBirthDate = Format(CDate(Date.FromOADate(CDbl(istrBirthDate)).ToString), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```