# Convert Julian Date and Time to DateTime in C# Micro Framework

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-micro-framework, julian-date

I found code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14554483/1082492 to convert a `DateTime` to a Julian Date but I can't find code to reverse the process and even more importantly included the time of day. I'm trying to do this in the .NET Micro Framework so what I can use is much more limited.

Comment: Why don't you consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5254812/961113) from the same post and just do the opposite

Comment: In the Micro Framework To/FromOADate doesn't exist

Comment: Look into NodaTime. https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/
It may not be usable but it should have code for what you need and it is open source.

Comment: Gave NodaTime and unless I'm wrong it doesn't have what I need

Answer (score 0):

Using NodaTime allows you to convert an Instant to Julian Date by inst.ToJulianDate(); conversely converting a Julian Date to an Instant jd.FromJulianDate().