# Combining Julian 'Days' with DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, wpf, date, delphi, textbox

I'm trying to convert this bit of Delphi code to C#:

```
Date1.Text:=FormatDateTime2('YYYY,JJJ/HHNNSS)
```

Which contains the year, the Julian day (with January 1st of each year being 1), and hours/minutes/seconds.

So an example for today would be `2016,054/090722`.

The `FormatDateTime2` is a very, very long function with zero comments and unhelpful variable names in the delphi code, and I'd rather not spend a long time trying to convert that over.

Normally I would have something like this:

```
<TextBox Name="Date1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='yyyy,JJJ/hhmmss'}" />
```

But the `JJJ` day part doesn't work of course, because it isn't part of normal System.DateTime. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Does it make sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248827/convert-datetime-to-julian-date-in-c-sharp-tooadate-safe?

Comment: In C#, there is no way to do it in `StringFormat` as far as I know but you can calculate it with using `DayOfYear` property.

Comment: This is a dupe, but I originally linked to a question going in the other direction. Could somebody else please close to an appropriate dupe. @pfinferno, the Delphi code you posted does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to post the FormatDateTime2 function written in the Delphi code, it was several hundred lines long and very messy (I didn't write it).

Comment: My point was that `FormatDateTime2('YYYY,JJJ/HHNNSS)` does not compile and is in any case incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you format it manually? `DateTime` has a [`DayOfYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Date1.Text = String.Format("{0},{1}/{2}", 
                 now.Year, 
                 now.DayOfYear.ToString("d3"), 
                 now.ToString("HHmmss"));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, did not realize they had a `DayOfYear`. Thank you very much!